# How to perform saveOrUpdate in Ebean

Tags: playframework, ebean

I want to perform  saveOrUpdate in ebean with playframework based on matched data.

I couldn't able to find such method  in ebean java api.

Where I can find this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just can call the `save()` method on the entity. Based on it's state Ebean will either update or save it in your repository. [This is stated in the documentation.](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/persist/#saves)

Sample when calling save on a newly constructed object:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.setOrderDate(new Date());
...
// insert the order
Ebean.save(order);
```

But when you fetch it from your repository Ebean will know that calling save will eventually do an update:

```
Order order = Ebean.find(Order.class, 12);
order.setStatus("SHIPPED");
...
// update the order
Ebean.save(order);
```

Disclaimer: *above samples are from the posted link.*

Comment: Is there any way to do it without fetching?

Comment: You can use updateQuery for this I think: https://ebean.io/docs/query/update